# C# - What's the difference between these two ways of instancing a class property?

Tags: c#

Basic C# question here.

What is the difference between creating an instance of a class property / field either as you declare it or in the constructor of the object in question. For example:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public MyObject = new MyObject();
}
```

vs

```
public class MyClass
{
    public MyObject;

    public MyCLass()
    {
        MyObject = new MyObject();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

A field with an initializer is initialized *before* the base constructor is called, whereas if the initializer is in the body, that only gets executed *after* the base constructor is called.

This can be relevant if the base constructor calls a virtual method - but personally I'd try to avoid that situation.

Sample code:

```
public class Base
{
    public Base()
    {
        Dump();
    }

    public virtual void Dump() {}
}

public class Child : Base
{
    private string x = "Initialized at declaration";
    private string y;

    public Child()
    {
        y = "Initialized in constructor";
    }

    public override void Dump()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(x); // Prints "Initialized at declaration"
        Console.WriteLine(y); // Prints "" as y is still null
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 Also, my understanding is that initializing a field at the declaration allows the compiler/JITer to do some optimizations that it wouldn't otherwise do for an initialization in the constructor. I *believe* I read this in the ".NET Framework Design Guidelines" as their justification for preferring field initialization as a "best practice", but I'm not certain anymore.

Comment: @Cody: Not sure, to be honest. I personally wouldn't take that into account when writing code - I'd just stick to the clearest way of expressing intentions.

Comment: @Jon Skeet mistake: Child class not inherited to Base in code

Comment: @Jon Skeet, Regarding to question, the compiler will convert example 2 (in question) to example 1, if it is seen in Reflector

Comment: @Adeel: That's basically a bug in Reflector, IMO. Look at the IL (which you can still do within Reflector) and you'll see there's a difference in terms of the ordering of the assignment and the base constructor call.

Answer (score 3):

I compile these C# code:

```
public class MyClass1
{
    public MyObject MyObject = new MyObject();
}
public class MyClass2
{
    public MyObject MyObject;

    public MyClass2()
    {
        MyObject = new MyObject();
    }
}
```

I got IL assembly:

MyClass1:

```
.class public auto ansi beforefieldinit test.MyClass1
       extends [mscorlib]System.Object
{
  .field public class test.MyObject MyObject
  .method public hidebysig specialname rtspecialname 
          instance void  .ctor() cil managed
  {
    // code size:       19 (0x13)
    .maxstack  8
    IL_0000:  ldarg.0
    IL_0001:  newobj     instance void test.MyObject::.ctor()
    IL_0006:  stfld      class test.MyObject test.MyClass1::MyObject
    IL_000b:  ldarg.0
    IL_000c:  call       instance void [mscorlib]System.Object::.ctor()
    IL_0011:  nop
    IL_0012:  ret
  } // end of method MyClass1::.ctor

} // end of class test.MyClass1
```

MyClass2:

```
.class public auto ansi beforefieldinit test.MyClass2
       extends [mscorlib]System.Object
{
  .field public class test.MyObject MyObject
  .method public hidebysig specialname rtspecialname 
          instance void  .ctor() cil managed
  {
    // code size:       21 (0x15)
    .maxstack  8
    IL_0000:  ldarg.0
    IL_0001:  call       instance void [mscorlib]System.Object::.ctor()
    IL_0006:  nop
    IL_0007:  nop
    IL_0008:  ldarg.0
    IL_0009:  newobj     instance void test.MyObject::.ctor()
    IL_000e:  stfld      class test.MyObject test.MyClass2::MyObject
    IL_0013:  nop
    IL_0014:  ret
  } // end of method MyClass2::.ctor
} // end of class test.MyClass2
```

It is prefectly clear that difference is only in the order of call to the base class constructor (System.Object::.ctor()), MyObject initializer (test.MyObject::.ctor()) and the class initializer (stfld class test.MyObject test.MyClass2::MyObject)

In the first case, MyClass1 initializes as follows:

- MyObject initializer
- class initializer (constructor assigment)
- base class initializer (base class constructor)

But, MyClass2 initializes by that order:

- base class initializer (base class constructor)
- MyObject initializer
- class initializer (constructor assigment)

Answer (score 2):

You can also use a static constructor that gets called before any other constructor where you can init static variables

```
public class Bus
{
   private static object m_object= null;

    // Static constructor:
    static Bus()
    {
        m_object = new object();

        System.Console.WriteLine("The static constructor invoked.");
    }

    public static void Drive()
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("The Drive method invoked.");
    }
}

class TestBus
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Bus.Drive();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's important to note that (in C#) the initializer assignment to the field will occur before the call to any base class constructor (as evidenced in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4602468/can-vb-net-be-forced-to-initialize-instance-variables-before-invoking-the-base-ty) about whether VB could be forced to do the same thing).

This means you can't use initializer syntax to reference a field of your base class (i.e. you can't directly translate this VB into C#):

```
Public Class Base
    Protected I As Int32 = 4
End Class

Public Class Class2
    Inherits Base

    Public J As Int32 = I * 10
End Class
```

Comment: Haha, I was just about to post that as a comment to Jon Skeet's answer.

Comment: @Artur: Where do you get off downvoting this without reading it first? Your little test compiled the code in **C#**. Damien's answer here as well as [my question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4602468/can-vb-net-be-forced-to-initialize-instance-variables-before-invoking-the-base-ty) that he links to explicitly point out that the behavior is **different in VB.NET**.

Comment: @Artur - which point isn't true? The assignment `MyObject = new MyObject()` in your answer (Class2) isn't an Initializer, it's just an assignment statement. Initializer has a specific meaning in C#

Comment: @Cody Gray: "...In C#, the initializer assignment to the field will occur before the call to any base class constructor" - that's a LIE

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever in MyClass2, the initializer ASSIGMENT to the field is called AFTER the base class constuctor call

Comment: @Artur - your code example Class1 shows that the *Field Initializer* happens before the *base class constructor*. Class2 doesn't *have* a Field Initializer.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: In MyClass2 ... "{ MyObject = new MyObject(); }" , this is an assigment, which initializes the class field, then, it HAS an class field assigment inside the MyClass2 constructor

Comment: @Artur - but that is not an *Initializer*. It's an assignment, we can both agree on that, but Initializer has a specific meaning in C#.