# NullReference Exception to an objet that I initialized as New List(Of)?

Tags: .net, vb.net, nullreferenceexception

Could someone explain why I obtain a NullReference Exception to an objet that I initialized as New List(Of)??

```
Module Module1
  ' MAIN =================================    
  Sub Main()
    Console.Clear()
    Console.WriteLine("Creating Bar")
    Dim myBar As New Bar()
    Console.ReadLine()
  End Sub    
End Module

Class Foo
  Public Overridable Property Test As String

  Public Sub New()
    Me.Test = "hello"
  End Sub
End Class

Class Bar
  Inherits Foo
  Private _MyString As New List(Of String)

  Public Sub New()
    MyBase.New()
  End Sub

  Public Overrides Property Test As String
    Get
      Return MyBase.Test
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
      MyBase.Test = value
      ' NULL REFERENCE EXCEPTION ???????!!!!!!!!!!!
      Console.WriteLine("{0}, and _MyString.Count = {1}", MyBase.Test, Me._MyString.Count)
    End Set
  End Property
End Class
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4602468/can-vb-net-be-forced-to-initialize-instance-variables-before-invoking-the-base-t

Comment: whats an `objet` do you mean `object`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Foo.New()` runs before the field initializers in `Bar()`.

The `New` part of `As New List(Of String)` is actually part of the `Bar.New()` constructor, which runs after `MyBase.New()`.

Comment: Don't call virtual members in a constructor.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182331.aspx