# Is it better to create a "New" Object in the constructor or in the class variable definitions area?

Tags: vb.net

Is it better to create the List Object in the constructor or in the class variable definitions area?  Do they end up doing the same thing?  When is one method prefered over the other?

Here's a sample Class definition:

```
Public Class CProject

    'Variable to hold a list of Load Objects, Instantiate here vs in New().
    Private m_LoadList As New List(Of CLoad)

    Public Property LoadList() As List(Of CLoad)
        Get
            Return m_LoadList
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As List(Of CLoad))
            m_LoadList = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Sub New()

    End Sub

End Class
```

Verses:

```
Public Class CProject

    'Variable to hold a list of Load Objects
    Private m_LoadList As List(Of CLoad)

    Public Property LoadList() As List(Of CLoad)
        Get
            Return m_LoadList
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As List(Of CLoad))
            m_LoadList = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Sub New()
        m_LoadList = New List(Of CLoad)
    End Sub

 End Class
```

Comment: If I remember correctly, there are may be some subtle differences if this is an inherited class, to do with whether the base class constructor is called before or after (and I think there is a difference between VB and C# here, but I can't find the relevant question), but for most purposes, they should be the same.

Comment: Found [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4602468/can-vb-net-be-forced-to-initialize-instance-variables-before-invoking-the-base-t) for the difference between VB and C# I was talking about.

Comment: Thanks. For the sake of clarity in my code, I opted for the second option.  This way everything that is initialized in the object happens in New() and there is no question what my intent is.

Answer (score 0):

it's closer to option #2 with a few changes:

```
Private m_LoadList As List(Of ADR) = Nothing


Public Property LoadList() As List(Of CLoad)
    Get
        If m_LoadList Is Nothing Then
            m_LoadList = New List(Of CLoad)
        End If
        Return m_LoadList
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As List(Of CLoad))
        m_LoadList = value
    End Set

End Property
```

this way you may reference the property and only create new instance when none is present.  Simpler coding with less chance of mistakes that create overhead..