# What comes first, Constructor or With{}?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I have a C# Class where the default `constructor` sets the properties default values.  Then, in a VB.Net project I am creating an instance and populating it from a DB using the `With{}`.

My question is, does the constructor happen first, or should it? 
I am seeing something weird and trying to figure out where to start looking.

---

Abbreviated Code

```
public class Contact
{
  public Guid ID {get; set;}
  public DateTime? InactiveDate {get; set;}

  public Contact()
  {
    this.ID = Guid.NewGuid();
    this.InactiveDate = null;
  }
}

Public Shared Function GetContact(ByVal contactID As Guid) As Models.Contact
  Dim results As Models.Contact = context.tblContacts.Where(Function(c) c.ID = contactID _
  .Select(Function(c) New Models.Contact() With { .ID = c.ID, .InactiveDate = c.InactiveDate}).SingleOrDefault()

  Return results
End Function
```

What I am seeing is my `InactiveDate` getting set to `null`.

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: And explain what weird means! :)

Comment: Constructor of an object will always go first, no matter what and how it's properties are initialized.

Comment: If the object tried to assign the properties before the object was contructed. Surley that would result in a null reference?

Comment: Added code. and here is 1 of the links that got me wondering -->http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5187092/why-does-c-sharp-set-private-variables-before-the-base-constructor-while-vb-net?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

The constructor will always go first, no matter what you do with the object.

Answer (score 1):

Constructor occurs first. As the name applies, it happens when the object is first constructed which always occurs before setting the properties/fields.

You can see this with a simple console application

```
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim n As New N()

        With n
            n.S = "This"
        End With

        Console.ReadKey()
    End Sub


    Class N
        Public Property S As String
            Get

            End Get
            Set(value As String)
                Console.WriteLine("Setter") //written second
            End Set
        End Property

        Sub New()
            Console.WriteLine("Constructor") //written first
        End Sub
    End Class
End Module
```

Comment: and it doesn't matter that the construtor is in a C# project and the rest is a VB.Net?  I had read a question here on SO that get me thinking down this path, see if I can find the link.

Comment: @RefractedPaladin Well, the purpose of the answer still applies.  Try it and find out if you're really that curious.  It's pretty easy to just check.

Answer (score 0):

The [object initializer syntax in C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397680.aspx) sets properties after the constructor runs.

The following two code snippets are equivalent.

```
Foo x = new Foo();
x.Property1 = "Yay!";
x.Property2 = 100;

Foo x = new Foo()
{
    Property1 = "Yay!",
    Property2 = 100
};
```

There are various reasons why someone would use the second syntax, such as the ability to avoid using a separate local variable in the following assignment. It can also help clarify that certain properties are being intentionally initialized with the object and the object is not usable until those assignments are complete.

```
fieldFoo.GetFoo().NextFoo = new Foo { Property1 = "Yay!", Property2 = 100 };
```

Comment: `The following two code snippets are equivalent.`  Well, not quite, there are differences, they just aren't relevant to this question.  Namely in the second case the object is first stored in a temp variable and `x` isn't set until all of the properties are set; this has atomicity implications in a multithreaded application.

Comment: @Servy You are trying to be sneaky, but I was also subtle. ;) My code is only syntactically correct if `x` is a local variable. Since it is not exposed to other code between the constructor and assigning a value to `Property2`, the semantic differences of the two assignments cannot be detected by other code, leaving them semantically equivalent.

Comment: Unless this snippet exists in a try block.  In that case, an exception when setting the properties will leave you with a partially initialized x in the former, and a null x in the latter.

Comment: @tcarvin `x` will be out of scope and inaccessible in that case

Comment: Ah yes, you are right!  Still, it was worth the comment to point out an important behavioral difference of using an object initializer for future readers.